# What datatype is suitable for storing latitudes and longitudes?

Tags: mysql

what should be the data type of latitudes and longitudes in general

Comment: my doubt here is:-
 does representing long or lats include direction imean like east or west ?

Comment: East and West is determined by the sign of the number.  East is positive; West is negative.

Comment: Dude then wat abt north and south?

Comment: i dont even know that they wud be represented please donot hesitate if im asking rong question

Comment: Maybe you should investigate how longitudes and latitudes are expressed, understand that, and then work out what you need to store them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `MySQL`, it should be [`Point`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gis-class-point.html), so that you can run efficient `SPATIAL` queries.

Comment: Could you please link to any documentation about this data type? Some googling seems to confirm its existence, but I can't find it in the official docs. Thanks!

Comment: @deceze: first Google result for `mysql point` yields this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gis-class-point.html

Comment: Weird. I guess I was googling for "point data type mysql" or something to that extend. A search for "point" on the MySQL site only yielded references to "floating-point"...

Answer (score 2):

For SQL Server 2000 and 2005, I've seen `Numeric(15,10)` for each coordinate used most often although I cannot speak to the correctness of that.

Sql Server 2008 has new `spatial` data types. See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.04.datatypes.aspx?pr=blog) for more on those (its a little more than half way down the page).

Answer (score 0):

I would say double if you want to store them in separate columns.

Answer (score 0):

I have used varchar2(40) under Oracle.

Comment: may i know y u r using varchar

Comment: WTF should previous comment mean? :mad: I looked at some english dictionaries, but words like "y", "u" and "r" seem have no meaning.
Sorry, english is not my language.

Comment: Is "WTF" part of your language? If u know what "WTF" means - u should know what "y" and "u" mean.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the language/DB you are using.
In general, its preferable to have it as float, in case of programming language.
and NUMBER(x,y) in case of sqlplus.

Answer (score 0):

in general int (on Intel x86 in 32bit mode) is sufficient (in 100 (")representation).
sign is used to indicate N/S and E/W.
brgds/gabriel